# my array enter my database but it erase the other arrays in my firebase database

Tags: php, arrays, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
<?php
//username
/*$mapId = $_GET['mapId']; 
$bike  = $_GET['bike'];
$lat   = (double)$_GET["lat"];
$lng   = (double)$_GET["lng"];
$ori   = (double)$_GET["ori"];*/

 $mapId = "2";
 $bike = "Yamaha ";
 $lat = 12346;
 $lng = 78945;
 $ori = 111111;
$time = time();

$url = 'https://granted-7cdeb.firebaseio.com/maps.json';
$arr = array($mapId =>array($bike =>array("coords"=>array("latitude"=>$lat, "longitude"=>$lng), "orientation"=>$ori, "timestamp"=>$time)));  
$data_string = json_encode($arr);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

So the issue I am having is when I use this code it sends my array to my firebase but after it sends the array. it deletes the array that is already in there I would like this to just add to my array but to update lat, lng, ori. I dont want it to erase the arrays that or already in there how can I accomplish this.

Comment: delete `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");` and use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`instead.

Comment: tired that now it dose not delete it but it keeps multiplying in stead of updating Yamaha

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't really have an indexed array append operation.  What it does offer is a "push" operation, where it will generate a new time-based unique string id and add your data under a child with that id.  You treat unique string IDs as a sort of array index.  This is the generally the way you append new data to a child rather than overwriting everything.

When using the [Firebase Realtime Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/), you will use a [POST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-post) request to perform a push.

Comment: could u give me a example on how to use this method I am new to coding